# PICKit 3 VDD Overcurrent

Tags: pic, programmer, pickit

The [PICKit 3 user guide](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Programmers/PICkit_3_User_Guide_51795A.pdf) tells me that it can source up to 30mA when in "Debugger Powered" mode, and that this mode can be used for independent programming in some cases. It also tells me the PICKit 3 has "software overcurrent and overcurrent protection".

I intend to use the debugger powered mode to program my boards. However, while my circuit draws way less than 30mA (around 5mA), the presence of decoupling capacitors in the power rails of the board means that, for some time, the 30mA limit will be exceeded.

My question is, can I be sure this brief overcurrent won't cause trouble? Should I add something to limit the current draw on the PICKit?

Comment: Decoupling caps on power up draw V/ESR =I current peaks for R*C=T duration(63% swing) normally this is not a huge energy drain but active current limiting may limit slew rate.

Answer (score 1):

It can, I often see a warning message coming up "The target circuit may require more power than the debug tool can provide. An external power supply might be necessary.
Connection Failed.". Large decoupling caps do make it worse, as does trying to program at 5V, since the PICkit draws power from the USB alone and that may already be marginal, so programming at 3.375V where possible works better. With the PICkit set to power the target, the Vdd pin remains live once it has connected once, and tends to be more successful on subsequent connections, presumably because the supply has stabilized before negotiation begins.

Comment: have you ever damaged a PICKit because of this? I'm very tempted to just retry the connection until it works (after the caps are charged it should), but I don't know if I can trust the PICKit's "software current limiting"

Comment: No, it seems to protect itself well enough, I've been using the same PICkit for a few years. My old ICD2 was capable of supplying far more current, I think 200mA, and never had any issues connecting, but it's a dinosaur now, so I had to replace it to support new chips.